# How do I make my camera follow my cube?

Tags: unity, monodevelop

I've recently started to learn some C# scripting in Unity. I've been able to make my PlayerCube move around using Vector3 Transform.translations, but I want my camera to follow my cube while moving around, and it's not working since Unity can't find PlayerCube. How do I make make it so it understands that there's a PlayerCube?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour {
    Player = GameObject.Find("PlayerCube");

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
    //  GameObject.Find(PlayerCube);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        Transform.LookAt (PlayerCube);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Is it at compile time or at build time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script.  Attach it to your camera, and place your cube in the Target spot in the inspector.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TargetFollower : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Tooltip("Target to be followed")]
    public Transform Target;
    [Tooltip("Mimic the Target's changes in x coordinate")]
    public bool FollowTargetX = true;
    [Tooltip("Mimic the Target's changes in y coordinate")]
    public bool FollowTargetY = true;
    [Tooltip("Mimic the Target's changes in z coordinate")]
    public bool FollowTargetZ = true;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Target)
        {
            Vector3 targetMovement = GetTargetMovement();
            UpdatePosition(targetMovement);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 oldTargetPosition;
    private Vector3 GetTargetMovement()
    {
        if (oldTargetPosition == Vector3.zero)
        {
            oldTargetPosition = Target.transform.position;
        }
        Vector3 newTargetPosition = Target.transform.position;
        Vector3 targetMovement = newTargetPosition - oldTargetPosition;
        oldTargetPosition = new Vector3(newTargetPosition.x, newTargetPosition.y, newTargetPosition.z);
        return targetMovement;
    }

    private void UpdatePosition(Vector3 targetMovement)
    {
        float xPosition = transform.position.x;
        float yPosition = transform.position.y;
        float zPosition = transform.position.z;
        if (FollowTargetX)
        {
            xPosition += targetMovement.x;
        }
        if (FollowTargetY)
        {
            yPosition += targetMovement.y;
        }
        if (FollowTargetZ)
        {
            zPosition += targetMovement.z;
        }
        Vector3 updatedPosition = new Vector3(xPosition, yPosition, zPosition);
        transform.position = updatedPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brownie points for providing axis selection.

Answer (score 1):

the fastest way is to make the camera child of the cube (in the editor), then in the Update() of the camera script use [LookAt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) :

```
void Update() {
    transform.LookAt(transform.parent);
}
```

Comment: Brownie points for simplicity. Doesn't get much simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your script and if it's the exact same in Unity you have a problem with the variable `Player` (no type and wrong name in Update ()). And you need to pass a **Transform** and not a **GameObject** in [tranform.LookAt ()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour {
    GameObject Player = GameObject.Find("PlayerCube");

    void Update () 
    {
        transform.LookAt (Player.tranform);
    }
}
```

I don't recommand making the camera a child of the cube as suggest @dnk-drone.vs.drones.

If you only want your camera to look at your object then the `transform.LookAt ()` is what you need. If you want to move the camera with the object you need to write it in your script.

You can also use a public reference for your object and drag it by using the Unity inspector.

Also, you can watch in the Unity/Standard Assets, a CameraFollow script exist already.